# Create Excel SUMIFS in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sumifs

I would like to create a new column called "SUMIFS" in another dataframe entitled "Subset" (i.e. Subset['SUMIFS'] = ...), and I am wondering if it is possible to perform an excel like SUMIFS operation across dataframes in pandas. The criteria for the SUMIFS would be:

```
excel =SUMIFS(AT:AT,AS:AS,AS2,AQ:AQ,AQ2,AM:AM,AM2)
```

---

```
DateOfOutage    Tech    Sites   Duration Modified
8/3/2019    3G  CAI0012 2
8/2/2019    2G  CAI0012 3
8/3/2019    2G  CAI0012 0.1
8/3/2019    3G  CAI0012 0.1
8/2/2019    3G  CAI0019 3
8/2/2019    2G  CAI0019 115
8/2/2019    3G  CAI0019 112
8/3/2019    2G  CAI0024 178
8/3/2019    3G  CAI0024 175
8/2/2019    2G  CAI0024 34
8/2/2019    2G  CAI0024 449
8/2/2019    3G  CAI0024 442
```

---

```
data['Duration Modified'][(data['Sites']==data['Tech'] == data['DateOfOutage'])].sum()
```

---

```
DateOfOutage    Tech    Sites   Duration Modified   Sumifs
8/3/2019    3G  CAI0012 2   2.1
8/2/2019    2G  CAI0012 3   3
8/3/2019    2G  CAI0012 0.1 0.1
8/3/2019    3G  CAI0012 0.1 2.1
8/2/2019    3G  CAI0019 3   115
8/2/2019    2G  CAI0019 115 115
8/2/2019    3G  CAI0019 112 115
8/3/2019    2G  CAI0024 178 178
8/3/2019    3G  CAI0024 175 175
8/2/2019    2G  CAI0024 34  483
8/2/2019    2G  CAI0024 449 483
8/2/2019    3G  CAI0024 442 442
```

Comment: Use `data['Sumifs'] = data.groupby(['DateOfOutage', 'Tech','Sites']).transform('sum')` or `df['Sumifs'] = df.groupby(['DateOfOutage', 'Tech','Sites'])['Duration Modified'].transform('sum')`

Comment: @Erfan - Sure, please add comemnts too. Thank you.